# how to save one line as one file with counter number names

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this:

```
VLLKHCGRMRRFLIRNLRSFLSHISLNTLKSQESKV
LLSSQAKMYFSLRENFYLEGGIETTFVPSGEVYSRSFLKGISRI
LNPNALPTSPISENWVMVRPIVAQISLRRMTPSAIGAQTEMA
MKLELLLAFKYLIPKRKRLSSSIVSAFSMGIVALVVWLSVVFMSVIHGLQQRWVGDLASLHSSIRIEPSDKYYESYYYQIDSHAEASQYIYKTIGEKLLCEQTDPYDPDVDFLLPEAFPDPEFSDNGEMIDPVRTANERMLSLFSSRKGSFVEFEEGMGHVHMDRAFRGHKGEPRALSQYIAYSSDILYQQRMLPFEETDYSTEVLNRFNASSEGWLADFLVLQEKFRGMSVILPVVYRDQGYRVGDTASLSVFSVKKEGEVRFPLRVIGFYNPGVSPFGGKTIFIDKELAASIRSESEGLGMHNGWQVFLPSVQDIPVMKQSIQKIFKESEVSSYWEISSLYDYEFFKPILDQLQSDQVLFSIVSFIVLIVACSNIVTMSILLVNNKKKEIGILKAMGVSSSRLQLVFGLCGACSGLVGALLGSILAALTLKNLGILTHWLSKLQGREAFNPSFFGEQLPQDFHLPTVICLSLGALVLAAISGAIPAQHVARMQVSDILKSE
MVILVEAKHISKVIQQQDVCIPILKDVSFQLHAGEVVAITGASGSGKSSLLHLLGTLDQPSSGQILFFGKQVRREELPIFRNCRIGFIFQNFYLLEDDSVINNVLMPAQIARKDTGQKSKARERALALLESVGLVDRRDEKGSLLSGGEKQRVAIARALMNDPEIVLADEPSGNLDHRTADTIHELLLALAEKHRGVLIVTHDRELAEKCHREEILRDGTLMQRQ
LKDTVTPNYHPGMIRRFRPLTQTSTRSGYHKSE
LHVSCLEWLSMITFTRTPLRIAWARAKKNSGLKKIYIKTKILSVAWLIAFKIIFDAALGIKRWIGM
LADPVTTVWKSANIVFLCWRVLPLVRRKTTLEF
LARRRSGSFRGGRRSVFGSLVFSLGSGEHLLGDGY
VGARVRIDANRLSIPSMIVFIANNRRGLWVTIPF
VEEVGSGGLKRSLYFKEEEPCTLITLRSWLEKKET
```

I want each line of the file to be saved in its own file whose name is the line number of the original (`1`,`2`,`3`, etc.). I also need a line added before each sequence starting with a `>` and then the line number.

So, `1.txt` would be:

```
>1
VLLKHCGRMRRFLIRNLRSFLSHISLNTLKSQESKV
```

and 2.txt:

```
>2
LLSSQAKMYFSLRENFYLEGGIETTFVPSGEVYSRSFLKGISRI
```

and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the `>` to be part of the output file? I wasn't sure if you meant to use the `>~ for formatting or if you're trying to create FASTA files. If FASTA, remember that you need `> sequence name` not `> sequence`.

Comment: yes, the output should be like:
>1
VLLKHCGRMRRFLIRNLRSFLSHISLNTLKSQESKV

Comment: Are you sure? That makes no sense and is not a valid FASTA file.

Comment: the seqence name will be 1 ,2 ,3 etc..

Comment: OK, that's not what you asked for. Please check my edit, is that what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '{print > NR".txt"}' file
```

`NR` is the current line number in `awk`, so the command above will print each line into a file whose name is the current line number plus `.txt`.

If you really want the sequences to have a `>` prepended, use this:

```
awk '{print ">"$0 > NR".txt"}' file
```

And if you want correct FASTA format (each sequence preceeded by a line starting with `>` and a sequence name) use this:

```
awk '{printf ">%s\n%s\n",NR,$0 > NR".txt"}' file
```

That will produce files like:

```
$ cat 3.txt 
>3
LNPNALPTSPISENWVMVRPIVAQISLRRMTPSAIGAQTEMA
```

Comment: I require the third option ... Thanks for your help and guidance.